# wpa_gui - X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, ssh, xorg

I am trying to use wpa_gui on my Pi2 from a windows machine using ssh inside MobaXTerm. When I do ssh -X pi@ I get

> X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
>
> wpa_gui: cannot connect to X server raspberrypi:11.0

When i try to check the `xauth` for the needed cookie it gives me a blank line.

Does anyone ahs an idea how to tackle that problem? Disk space is enough available.

Answer (score 0):

You might try `ssh -Y` (instead of `-X`).  As long as it's a local connection between two machines you trust there shouldn't be any compromise.  `-X` blocks forwarding of some X11 Protocol Messages that `-Y` passes.  I'm not sure it's this, but try it.